# How can I configure DansGuardian to filter https traffic?

Tags: dansguardian

I am having issues configuring DansGuardian to filter https traffic.

Is there a way to force https traffic to go through a DansGuardian filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTPS provides an encrypted channel from end to end (S in HTTPS is for SSL; Secure Sockets Layer). So no, there's no way to inspect the contents of anything over an HTTPS connection. That's the whole purpose of it in the first place!

Comment: Squid can be configured to do a MITM and intercept HTTPS traffic: http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Intercept/SslBumpExplicit Of course this requires that the user installs a new CA in the browser, but it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

While it's my understanding that it's not ready for prime-time just yet, there is a fork of DansGuardian in the works called Archangel, which will filter BOTH HTTP AND HTTPS websites.  For more information, take a look at its homepage at [its Google Code homepage](https://code.google.com/p/archangel/) and its [Sourceforge page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/archangelfilter/).